# ggplot2: How to change position of tick/grid lines to align with dates in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, linegraph, timeserieschart

I am trying to plot some data where my x-axis is date. Please see the sample data below.

```
Test.Data <- data.frame(weekBeginDate = c("2017-10-21", "2017-10-28", "2017-11-04", "2017-11-11", "2017-11-18", "2017-11-25", "2017-12-02", "2017-12-09", "2017-12-16", "2017-12-23", "2017-12-30"), Temperature = sample(1:11))
```

When I plot this data using ggplot using the following code, I get the below output.

```
Test.Data$weekBeginDate <- as.Date(Test.Data$weekBeginDate)
Test.Data.plot <- ggplot(Test.Data, aes(x = weekBeginDate,y = WeeklyAvg)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Temperature), size=1.25) + 
    labs(y = "Air Temperature [°C]", x = "Date") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 weeks", date_minor_breaks = "weeks") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: ggplot graph showing time series of sample temperature data]

As you can see, the tick or grid lines on the graph don't align with the dates that were used in the data (e.g., the labeled dates on the graph are 2017-11-13 and 2017-12-11, whereas I would like them to be 2017-11-11 and 2017-12-09, for example). Is there a way to change the date on which the grid lines appear?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: You can specify breaks. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `breaks` in `scale_x_date` to your desired x values, which in this case is the whole vector of dates in `Test.Data$weekBeginDate`:

```r
ggplot(Test.Data, aes(x = weekBeginDate,y = WeeklyAvg)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Temperature), size=1.25) + 
    labs(y = "Air Temperature [°C]", x = "Date") +
    scale_x_date(breaks = Test.Data$weekBeginDate) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I had tried to specify breaks (or minor breaks, in this case) but hadn't used the correct notation. I didn't realize that I needed to use the dataframe$vector notation - since the data set was specified earlier in the code string, I thought I could get away with just using the vector string name. I appreciate the clarification!